# Exit execution on custom controller class in CodeIgniter to stop rendering views

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I created a class `MyController` and put in in `core` folder. It extends `CI_Controller`;

Then I created a controller Foo that extends myController. I wanted to do something like `exit()` in a certain point of the Foo's `__construct` function.

```
class Foo extends MyController{
    private $formats = array('json');

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //do something
        exit();
    }
}
```

What I want with this is to stop rendering views in certain cases. But it's not working, if I go to `myproject/foo/whatever` it still goes to `whatever` action and renders the *404* default view

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you code enter into your `Foo __construct`  ???

Comment: @Saty well yes, as you can see by the example given. it tries to 'exit' at the end of the construct. but it still looks for the action, and after realising it doesn't exist, it renders an error 404. how can I stop the exection?

Comment: just use this url `myproject/foo` and check what it show??

Comment: 404. I want a blank page. but I want it to ignore the action passed as parameter

Comment: also post the code of controller `MyController`

Comment: it means you code not enter into your foo controller!!

Comment: You probably need codeigniter Hooks http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: @AnkitPise what hook is the best option for me? `display_override`? every child of MyController must have this functionality.

Comment: no hooks needed. Have you tried var_dumping or echoing out before the exit() to make sure that you are at least arriving there?

Comment: hey @CodeGodie I am. if I echo 'hello' and exit on MyController's constructor it will not continue executing Foo. but it still checks for the action on Foo and throws a 404 if the function doens't exist. I wanted it to do nothing. it makes me think there is something like a buffer that is already filled with the 404 error at that point and is sent as response after the exit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Controller name. You need to follow Codeigniter's naming convention.

Change the name of the class in the Core folder to start with `MY_` such as `MY_main_controller`, rename your classes, and it should work.

**[Extending Core Classes](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class)**

Comment: can I leave it on `system/core` folder?

Comment: yes you can, you must. It needs to be in `application/core`

Comment: i named it MY_Controller, extended MY_Controller on Foo, placed it at application/core and named the file My_controller.php but it says the class was not found

Comment: in config.php is this set : `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` ?

Comment: yes, it is, exactly like this. it's probably not autoloading the file. what should the filename be?

Comment: dont know.. maybe i can help u through Teamviewer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81933/discussion-between-codegodie-and-victor-ferreira).